# Sorting by multiple fields chosen from a <select>

Tags: angularjs

I recently had an answer on how to sort by a single field that I select from a `<select>` dropdown.

**html**:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  Sort by: <select ng-model="sortField" ng-options="o.label for o in fields"></select>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="inverse"> inverse
  </label>

  <hr>

  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data|orderBy:sortField.key:inverse">
      <td>{{row.id}}</td>
      <td>{{row.number}}</td>
      <td>{{row.text}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**js**:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    { label: 'ID',   key: 'id' },
    { label: 'Nr.',  key: 'number' },
    { label: 'Text', key: 'text' }
  ];

  $scope.sortField = $scope.fields[2];
  $scope.inverse = false;

  $scope.grid = {
    data: [
      { id: 1, number: 4, text: 'A' },
      { id: 2, number: 3, text: 'E' },
      { id: 3, number: 2, text: 'B' },
      { id: 4, number: 1, text: 'D' },
      { id: 5, number: 0, text: 'C' }
    ]
  };
}]);
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/ezadat/1/

This works very well but now I would like to allow the sorting by multiple fields. For example in this case the "number" and then "text" field.

Has anyone tried any solutions on how to do this?  If so I would appreciate any advice they could give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is adding another entry to the `fields` like this if you want AngularJS to sort on *number* first and then *text*:

```
{ label: 'Number - Text', key: ['number', 'text'] }
```

The expression [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) takes can be an *array*:

> Array: An array of function or string predicates. The first predicate
>   in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent,
>   the next predicate is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could try concatenating the fields you want to sort on and then making them not visible - so you have an invisible sort key.